# Longer than usual compilation time in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compilation

Xcode is taking a much longer than usual time to run my project on my actual device. When running on a simulator, the compiletime is much faster. Here's the part of the report that's taking a long time in the report navigator -

["Run Custom Shell Script"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3bRt.png)

and ["Copy Swift stand libraries"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov7qX.png)

I tried messing with the podfile to reduce the time but that didn't work either. Here's the code in there -

```
target 'Pluto' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift3'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Xcode was running very slow in general. It happened to be a `keychain` issue. Delete all your certificates and re-add them.